# 2-pairings in a set A, where |A|=8

Tags: combinatorics

The task is to assign 8 tennis players into pairs of 2 for a bracket.

The answer is 105, for which my textbook used the method:
1. Select the 4 pairs, for which there are 8C2*6C2*4C2*2C2 ways.
2. Divide by the number of permutations for the pairs, which is 4P4.
(8C2*6C2*4C2*2C2)/4P4 = 105 pairings.

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong with this other method that I tried:
1. Select all combinations of 4 players for the left side of the bracket, 8C4.
2. For each such combination, pair it with all permutations of the other 4 players, 4P4.
3. This should overestimate by a factor of 2 (mirror images), because the left-side {a,b,c,d} will duplicate with the left-side {e,f,g,h}.

However, (8C4*4P4)/2 = 840, which is still off by a factor of 8. What duplicates have a neglected to remove?

Comment: I think you will have to divide by $4^2$ instead of 2, and that will give you $105$

Comment: Do you know why it's $4^2$?

Comment: I figured this out... For every combination chosen on the left, e.g. {a, b, c, d} there is more than one duplicate. 

The duplicate of which I was aware was the one you get by switching the left/right:
{a, b, c, d} {e, f, g, h}
{e, f, g, h} {a, b, c, d}

But there are actually more duplicates, obtained from any pair or combination of pairs that can be switched:
{a, b, c, d} {e, f, g, h}
{e, f, g, h} {a, b, c, d} (reverse duplicate)
{e, b, c, d} {a, f, g, h} (1-pair switch duplicate)
{e, f, c, d} {a, b, g, h} (2-pair switch duplicate)